# A certain partial derivative

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

Hi I am reviewing partial derivatives. 
For the question below, I am not sure why $(x-1)$ appears. Could anyone give me a explanation on this?

$y = x\sin(z)e^{-x}$

$\partial y/\partial x = -e^{-x}(x-1)\sin(z)$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Apply the product rule, then factorise the resulting expression.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer :) If I use product rule, I thought the "-x" part be -1 and e^(-x) part be the same e^(-x). Then where exactly did the "x-1" come from?

Comment: @user3368526: $$\big(xe^{-x}\big)'=x\big(e^{-x}\big)'+x'e^{-x}=\ldots\;?$$

Comment: There are two factors which are functions of $x$, namely $x$ and $e^{-x}$. Differentiating the $x$ gives $\sin(z)e^{-x}$, and differentiating the $e^{-x}$ gives you $-x\sin(z)e^{-x}$. Add these together and factorise. (And, apparently, pull out a factor of $-1$ too.)

Comment: Actually, I didn't fully understand it yet. I got the below which should be wrong.
sin(z)e^-x+(-xsin(z)e^-x -> (1-x)(sin(z)e^-x)
I didn't have a negative and (x-1).
I will appreciate your advice!

Comment: Note that $1-x=-(x-1)$.

Comment: AH I should've noticed.. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Notice, we have $$y=x\sin (z)e^{-x}$$ $$\frac{\partial }{ \partial x}(y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}(x\sin (z)e^{-x})$$ $$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=\sin(z)\frac{\partial }{\partial x}(xe^{-x})$$  $$=\sin(z)\left(x\frac{d}{dx}(e^{-x})+\sin(z)e^{-x}\frac{d}{dx}(x)\right)$$ $$=\sin(z)\left(x(-e^{-x})+\sin(z)e^{-x}(1)\right)$$
$$=\sin(z)\left(-xe^{-x}+e^{-x}\right)$$ $$=-e^{-x}(x-1)\sin(z)$$

Hence, we get $$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\frac{\partial y}{ \partial x}}=\color{blue}{-e^{-x}(x-1)\sin(z)}}$$

Your answer is correct.